# Fastest way to count equals elements in two 2D arrays (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, multidimensional-array

I have two 2D array that contains only 0 and 1. These two arrays have the **same size** and are relatively small (max 20x20). I have to count how many **equal elements** there are, considering the position. Since I have to call this function many times within my code I would like to know if there is a **faster way** to do this (including unsafe assembly). I had the bad idea of ​​parallelizing the sum of each row, but the result is worse.

```
public int Compare(byte[,] a, byte[,] b)
{
    int score = 0;

    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return -1;

    for (int y = 0; y < a.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < a.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            if (a[x, y] == b[x, y])
                score++;
        }
    }

    return score;
}

public int CompareParallel(byte[,] a, byte[,] b)
{
    int[] yScore = new int[a.GetLength(1)];

    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return -1;

    ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.For(0, a.GetLength(1), y => {
        for (int x = 0; x < a.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            if (a[x, y] == b[x, y])
                yScore[y]++;
        }
    });

    return yScore.Sum();
}
```

MAIN:

```
int score;
int iterations = 100000000;
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
byte[,] a = new byte[4, 2] { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };
byte[,] b = new byte[4, 2] { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

s.Start();
    
for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    score = Compare(a, b);

Console.WriteLine($"TEST1 - Elapsed: {s.Elapsed.Seconds} seconds");

s.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    score = CompareParallel(a, b);

Console.WriteLine($"TEST2 - Elapsed: {s.Elapsed.Seconds} seconds");
```

PRINT:

```
TEST1 - Elapsed: 3 seconds
TEST2 - Elapsed: <TOO MUCH>
```

Comment: Paralllizing 20x20 is probably not worth it, given you need proper synchronization (which you haven't). This is done in microseconds. Parallelize the outer loop instead.

Comment: A faster way? Try C++ or Assembly if you can code that. For every performance question, please specify the following: 1. How long does it take now? 2. What is your machine spec? 3. What is the maximum time it may take? Without that information, it's premature optimization. "As fast as possible" will take a team of 2 PhDs 11 years to implement until they agree that they have found the optimal solution.

Comment: thanks, I have already parallelized the outer loop, so I wanted to know if it can be optimized at a lower level

Comment: No, you have parallelized the inner loop. You call CompareParallel() from a normal loop. You have Parallel.For inside CompareParallel.

Comment: "I wanted to know if it can be optimized" - Sure, it can. But as I said before ...

Comment: I have parellized the outer loop but I didn't include it in this code

Comment: I've just done a *very* quick test on my laptop, and using `byte[][]` instead of `byte[,]` made it over three times faster... so you might want to consider whether that's feasible for you.

Comment: Small optimisation: if `a == b` (meaning they are the same instance), return the number of elements in the array

Comment: for me byte[][] is 2x faster, not bad

Comment: Since you output only Elapsed.Seconds, your code might actually run for 7 minutes without you noticing it. Use ElapsedMilliseconds if you want the total time. Other than that I ask you again to provide your machine specs, because it takes 9 seconds on my machine.

Comment: With jagged arrays, the same optimisation (`a == b`) can be done on each iteration of the outer loop again. Depending on where the arrays come from, this can increase the efficiency a lot, or it can slightly reduce the efficiency, if they can never be the same instance.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest, but probably not fastest, version, just to have something to compare against:

```
a.Zip(b, (l, r) => l == r).Count(b => b);
```

However, there is a very important optimization you have missed:

> for (int y = 0; y < a.GetLength(1); y++)

`.GetLength()` is *slow*, so you should call this *once* outside the loop, not each iteration. This should make your code a few times faster. You might also want to test if reversing the loop order help, you want to access values sequentially, but I can't remember if that means putting y or x in the outer loop.

If this is insufficient I would recommend making your own 2D array that wraps a regular 1D array. First of all this lets you get rid of one of the loops and removes some index calculation. This should also let you use [SIMD intrinstics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/).

You could also test to see if some unrolling of the loop helps, a possible bottleneck might dependencies between instructions, so if you could reduce this it might help a bit.

I would not expect a parallel loop to help at all if you only have 400 bytes to compare, that should be to little work to be worth running on multiple threads. I'm also not sure if native code will help a great deal over well optimized C# code, if you make it easy for the jitter it should produce fairly good code. But I'm not a C++ developer, so there might be something possible in native code that is not possible from c#.

Comment: Caching the results of GetLength() gave a factor 3 increase on my machine.
Switching from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5 gave another factor 1.8 increase.
Times measured on Ryzen 7 2700X in Release Build running without debugger.